# Unable to use concate in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

```html
async def my_blog(self, user: CurrentUser = None):
        stmt = (
            select(Blogs)
            .where(Blogs.user_id == 1)
            .options(
                load_only(Blogs.title, Blogs.description),
                joinedload(Blogs.user).load_only(
                    UserModel.first_name,
                    UserModel.last_name,
                    func.concat(UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name).label(
                        "full_name"
                    ),
                ),
            )
        )
        response = await self.session.execute(statement=stmt)
        return response.scalars().all()
```

I am learning sqlalchemy. please help me out I don't know what wrong I am doing this

I want full_name to be returned along with other columns.

its raising AttributeError: Neither 'Label' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'is_property'

Comment: ORM options are designed to work with model instrumented attributes (columns etc), not arbitrary expressions.